# New .. questions for - Stack Exchange - not checking already answered?

Tags: bug, email-notification

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a missing feature.

I get notifications for new questions, and right now (21:42) I got an e-mail.

It's telling me:

> The following item was added to your Stack Exchange "nlog" feed.
>
> Use Nlog for CloudwatchLog 
>   [Use Nlog for CloudwatchLog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42311867/use-nlog-for-cloudwatchlog)

But I already answered [this question 6 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42315253/201303)!

Do I get this email because it's not marked as answered? Or is the email notification checker not checking if the user already posted an answer at all?

Answer (score 1):

> Or is the email notification checker not checking if the user already posted an answer at all?

No. It does not, and for me it doesn't need to really. You have an edge case which needs quite some programming to fix it for little gain.